# how to handle IPC between three or more processes?

Tags: process, ipc, message-queue

I have three or more processes which need to communicate with each other. All are not bi directional, meaning, process1 may have to talk to process2 but process2 need not talk to process1.but some are bi directional.

I was thinking of Message queues.But I've read, only one process can register for notification at a time. That eliminates the usage of MQs, I guess.

And no other IPC seems fit for this.

Please suggest me if I were thinking right.Also suggest me method of implementing my requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There exist many implementations of message queues. If you are talking about publish-subscribe messaging, there are usually many subscribers. For other middleware you can have any number of uni- or bi-directional communication, but rarely broadcast.

You might want to check our [MsgConnect](http://www.eldos.com/msgconnect/) (open-source), it lets your applications send messages to each other (both with and without reply) on the same system or across network.

Comment: Thank you Eugene...Please suggest me existing mechanism which avoids usage of any other library as such MsgConnect.

Comment: Can I manage IPC between three or more processes with only single message queue, considering bi-directional communication?

Comment: @crusader with publish-subscribe messaging, yes - you have a single bus on the server to which client processes are connected. They can broadcast the messages on the bus. This depends on particular implementation of the message queue.